# Como pegar uma imagem da view (html) e mandar para um controller (php) utilizando codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-charts, mpdf

Preciso passar uma imagem da minha *view* para o *controller*, seja só a string com a url ou seja o elemento html inteiro, pra mim tanto faz porque vou utilizar para montar um pdf através do *mpdf*, estou utilizando *angular* e *codeigniter* e o *mpdf* não está me deixando gerar através de requisição AJAX, estou jogando os parametros diretamente na URL e resolvendo a rota através do *routes.php* do *ci* para chamar diretamente uma função no controller, para gerar o pdf, o problema é que a URL da minha imagem é a que a google gera para imagem em png do *google charts*, é gigantesca e não consigo fazer jogando direto na URL como os outros parâmetros, alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Seu texto esta um pouco confuso. Resolveria passar um base64 para o servidor e utilizar ele la? Outra alternativa é disparar um form com a imagem via js.

Comment: eu acho que o ideial mesmo seria encurtar a url da imagem que o google chart gera, de maneira dinâmica, acho que o base64 seria mais trabalhoso não? e o form não seria uma opção porque eu preciso que o botão seja um link

Comment: O form pode ser escondido e o disparo dele pode ser o click, tudo isso com js.

Comment: No caso do base64, eu realmente nunca fiz assim. Mas, sinceramente, parece que a melhor solução é você enviar via POST mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Enviando via POST com jQuery:

```
var img_url = 'linkgeradoGcharts'
$.post( "suarota", { img: img_url } ).done(function(data){
   alert(data)
})
```

Pegando o request no CodeIgniter:

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html

`$this->input->post('img');`

Comment: não deu erro mas tbm não deu certo, o img_url vai receber a url gerada certo? o problema acho que tá na rota, porque o angular tá tratando rota nesse caso

Comment: Eu nao entendo muito de Angular, mas deve haver alguma forma ai de voce chamar as rotas da API externa e nao do Angular. Nem que especifique o link absoluto da rota. Mas, se nao me engano, o angular so pega os links a partir do `#/` nao é? Tente colocar o link completo da rota, ex: `http://minhaaplicacaolocal.app/minharota`

Comment: na verdade assim eu até consigo resolver a rota, mas eu quero usar essa variavel que é o link em uma rota já resolvida entende? tipo uma rota que já me direciona pra uma função na classe controller, queria simplismente pegar o valor dentro dela, não sei o que essa rota chamaria no routes.php do codeigniter

Comment: quando eu resolver a rota no js eu não vou ter que chamar um método da minha classe controller?

Comment: coloco o método no qual que eu estou usando o _$this->input->post('img');_

Comment: Teoricamente, só de criar a rota e apontar o Controller, tudo já chegará nele. Seja Post ou Get, entao ai você conseguirá pegar a imagem.
Sobre o `$this->input->post('img')` você conseguirá usar se o controller tiver uma instancia do input injetado nele, provavelmente algo padrão no codeigniter.